# Python can not import an existing file

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am building the google detection api model and I am in the final step - training. 
After running this code

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco.config
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 27, in <module>
from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'input_reader_pb2'
```

I do have both the proto and the python

> input_reader_pb2

files. I would be very happy if someone actually helps me and doesn't redirect me to other threads.

Comment: General hint: if your error is an "ImportError" -> google it. Because folks on stackoverflow usually can't reproduce this kind of error unless they have a broken library installation as well(and broken in the same way), therefore it's a waste of time ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting the link.. But it is from tensorflow itself.

Please find this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3933

It says you have to do the below steps:

```
cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Also go through the conversation fully there.

Comment: .. I am getting this error.....'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.